# How can I retrive helm charts stored in Amazon ECR repository using golang application

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

I want to retrive charts stored in ECR using helm sdk of golang, also the pull will happen from pod running in cluster, and the deployment will be on the same cluster. So using those charts which were pulled I need to deploy it on EKS Cluster

I was trying to use helm sdk in golang to connect with ecr but I was not able to do so.

Comment: if you provide the code you are using, it will be helpul to answer your question